# How to stop Django caching view results

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django framework.

I am using :

```
 python==2.7_win32
    Django==1.11.3
    djangorestframework==3.6.3
```

I am creating an API which do not involve any database.

**Flow of data is :**

1. User Request in JSON
2. Invoking method in Django's views.py
3. This method calls **my local package that is not part of django** and gets result
4. Return this result in the Response

**Problem is :** 
It works perfectly in the first request but on the next request it gives previous result only.

I found that django caches the `Queryset` and we can force to read new data by adding `all()` method.

But my code do not involve any Database or Model. So I think QuerySet will also not created.But still my results are getting cached somehow. how can I stop it?

Here is my view :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@never_cache
def filter_details(request):

    data = {}
    data['data'] = {}
    result_array = []
    error = None 

    try:
        attr1 = request.data.get("attr1")
        attr2 = request.data.get("attr2")
        local_package_obj = local_package.ClassName(attr1)
        result_array = local_package_obj.get_some_data_as_array(attr2)
    except Exception as e:
        error = str(e)

    data['data']['important'] = result_array
    data['error'] = error

    return Response(data)
```

Even after applying different values for att1 and attr2 I am getting same results.
I have checked local package. I works properly. The problem is in caching only.

Comment: Django doesn't do anything like that by default. Can you give us more detail about what your "local package" does, and how it works?

Comment: local package reads a local file , gets some data and returns array of it. Here attr1 decides which file to be read and stored as instance variable. Now a method reads from that file and generates result.

Comment: The error is almost certainly in that package; you should post that code.

Comment: I have tested local package.It works properly.  Even here in django if I restart the server then in the first query it gives desired result.But on next query it doesn't.  Local package is too large in no. of lines. so can not post here. But I am sure it is working well.It just involves file read-writes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I works properly. The problem is in caching only.

No it doesn't work properly.
If you face some caching issues, you probably have a scope issue somewhere and you're not aware of it.

For example, if you have something like this in your module:

```
# This is a file
queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()

def my_function():
    return list(queryset)  # list() will force the QS evaluation
```

If you call `my_function()` it'll will return a list of instances. Add or remove some instances and you won't see a change.

The reason is `queryset` is evaluated once and will stay evaluated.

if you change the code as:

```
def my_function():
    return list(queryset.all())
```

you'll see the list change. This is because `.all()` will return a new queryset which means it is not evaluated.

Most of the time, I prefer to be explicit and create the queryset directly from the function:

```
def my_function():
    return list(SomeModel.objects.all())
```

Comment: My local package stores data that it read into memory. Now I am making second POST request to Django with new data and that read new file and stores its result in memory again.  Do that mean last file's data did not removed from memory??

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means. But why can't tell you why because you won't show us the code. Probably you are storing something in a class-level variable instead of an instance one, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @RajShah it depends how the code is written. My answer show what not to do and what to do. You have to adapt your package code to fix the issue.

Comment: **The problem was scope of the local module.**

There was a global variable in the local package and Django's view was interacting with that global variable by calling a method which reads and updates that global variable. So, when ever a new request comes to Django it indirectly updates global variable and therefore next request was getting affected.